# Angular JS with Yii 2, hide # from url

Tags: php, angularjs, yii

I have started a project, with angular Js on frontend, and yii2 framework as back end. Everything is working fine, expect the fact that the Site url contains a #/ every time, and it is annoing. I would like to hide it. I tried the following :

```
        if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
        //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); will cause an error $location in HTML5 mode requires a  tag to be present! Unless you set baseUrl tag after head tag like so: <head> <base href="/">

        // to know more about setting base URL visit: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

        // if you don't wish to set base URL then use this
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
    }
```

( base url in head is set... )

I tried the following url : site/test ( site/#/test is working! )

But I am getting an error from the framework :

```
exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request "test".' in C:\xampp\htdocs\angularyii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php:462
Stack trace:

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\angularyii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(83): yii\base\Module->runAction('test', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\angularyii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\angularyii\frontend\web\index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}
```

`Next exception` `'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Page not found.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\angularyii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php:95`
Stack trace:

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\angularyii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\angularyii\frontend\web\index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#2 {main}
```

How can i solve this problem ? Thank you very much.

Comment: server side should send index.html for every request.

Comment: what do you mean exactly ? @YOU

Comment: site/ works right? because server send index.html or run index.php, do the same for every routes inside site/ except assets. may be RewriteRule . index.php in .htaccess - take a look at this implementation - https://github.com/drumaddict/angular-yii